# Rails partials not picking up javascript format

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ujs

I've added JavaScript partials many times before, but admittedly not for a while. The short of it is, I'm missing something stupid.

When I try to render partial 'deleteme.js' at the end of this view:

/app/views/projects/myview.html.slim:

```
h2 Stuff goes here

render partial: '/projects/thisworks' # Render html partial

render partial: '/projects/deleteme.js' # Render js partial...fails
```

Which renders this partial:

/app/views/projects/_deleteme.js.erb:

```
console.log("Oh FFS, Work");
```

I get:

> ActionView::MissingTemplate in Projects#show
>
> Showing
>   /Users/aj/Web/Rails/sh3/app/views/projects/show.html.slim
>   where line #5 raised:
>
> Missing partial /projects/deleteme with {:locale=>[:en],
>   :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :slim, :jbuilder,
>   :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:   *
>   ...

The incriminating bit is that it's searching for formats => [:html] only, but I thought appending .js automatically tells rails to search for javascript. If anyone has any ideas as to why it's not finding the JS template, I'd be really appreciative. Action code is a very basic:

```
def show
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 /app/views/projects/_deleteme.js.erb:
```

You are getting partial naming intertwined with Javascript action naming!

```
 /app/views/projects/deleteme.js.erb:
```

rename your javascript file,  remove the _

You have to make sure your show responds to js

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html
  end
end
```

Comment: Many thanks brad. Good news is the error has now changed to :formats=>[:js], bad news is, error is otherwise the same. Any thoughts?

Comment: You have to make sure the controller action is told to respond to AJAX

def show
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js
     format.html
   end

Comment: I think you need to edit your original question,  and more code,  and add the exact errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a partial inside a slim template so it expects to find

```
app/views/projects/_deleteme.js.slim
```